# How to use a data frame you've operated on with a function (python)

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I am working on Jupyter Notebook. I have multiple data frames in which I am comparing data between them. Before I compare the data between these data frames, I need to clean up some of the strings. I need to remove the double quotes (") AND I need to get rid of the NaN values in the empty cells.

In order to do this for one data frame, titled df1970, I created two functions:

```
df1970['Title'] = pd.Series(df1970['Title']).str.replace('"', '')
df1970= df1970.replace(np.nan, "", regex=True)
```

When I refer to df1970 downstream, it gives me the cleaned data frame. However, I have a dataset titled df1966 and I want to remove the double quotes and replace NaN *without* typing the whole above code again. So I created a function:

```
def cleanupdataset(df):
    df['Title'] = pd.Series(df['Title']).str.replace('"','')
    df= df.replace(np.nan, "", regex=True)
    return df
```

Then, when I call:

```
cleanupdataset(df1966)
```

...it gives me a nice clean dataset of 1966 that I want to use downstream.

My later functions call USETHISDF as the title of the data frame on which to operate. So this time around I want to use my nice new and clean df1966, so I redefine it:

```
 cleanupdataset(df1966)

 USETHISDF = df1966
```

But when I call it to check that it's cleaned...

```
 USETHISDF
```

it uses gives me the non-cleaned version of df1966. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not change the initial dataframe in-place, but returns a new dataframe. In order to see the changes you have to use the return value of your function:

```
USETHISDF = cleanupdataset(df1966)
```